# Find graphs in DB that are subgraphs of an input graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 1,000,000 small unrelated graphs in my Neo4j DB. I'd like to input a big graph (as lists of nodes and relationships) and find my unrelated graphs as subgraph of the big graph.

Are there any function or approaches in Cypher (Neo4j) which can simplify this for me? Thanks.

[UPDATE]

Here is an example with 2 graphs in the DB, and a submitted input graph. So, how can I find Graph 1 (from picture) in submitted graph?

[image]

Comment: This is basically a set intersection. Are you looking for something more sophisticated or faster than that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question: your DB has a million nodes without any relationships and you want to provide input data to add relationships between those nodes.

Here is a simple example of how to do that.

I assume your nodes all look something like this (where the `id` is unique):

```
(:Foo {id: "a", x: 123, ... and so forth ...})
```

and you want to connect the appropriate `Foo` nodes with `BAR` relationships. In this simple example, the relationships have no properties.

I also assume your input is in a CSV file named "bar_data.csv" whose beginning looks like this (`start`/`end` are the the `id`s of each new `BAR` relationship's start/end nodes):

```
start,end
a,b
b,x
j,w
... and so forth ...
```

Here is a sample Cypher query to load the input CSV file and create the relationships (in batches of 20000 per transaction, to avoid running out of server resources). You can tweak the batch size.

```
:auto // :auto line is needed when using IN TRANSACTIONS option in Neo4j Browser
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///bar_data.csv' AS row
CALL {
  WITH row
  MATCH (start:Foo), (end:Foo)
  WHERE start.id = row.start AND end.is = row.end
  CREATE (start)-[:BAR]->(end)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 20000 ROWS
```

You will need to read the [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) documentation to see how to configure the server, where the file can be stored, what the file URL can look like, and so forth.

Also the query will run *much faster* if you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `:Foo(id)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It can be the first step, but I added an example with picture to understanding the core of my task.